# Understand finance from its origin

Tags: terminology

The definition of Finance in [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/finance) is:

> The management of large amounts of money, especially by governments or large companies.

its origin is:

> Late Middle English: from Old French, from finer ‘make an end, settle a debt’, from fin ‘end’ (see fine). The original sense was ‘payment of a debt, compensation, or ransom’; later ‘taxation, revenue’. Current senses date from the 18th century, and reflect sense development in French.

So the keyword of 'finance' origin is the due overtime whereas the current meaning is about management.

How to understand the jump?

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary, under etymology for "finance, n.1", includes a note _The senses now current are adopted from modern French._ Sound like, to understand how the word changed meaning, you might have to look at how the meaning changed in French. Also, you might get better answers from https://english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you've got *lots* of debt, and that debt is due at many different times, there are intermediate partial payments, you've got to ensure that you've got enough money to pay the debts... that requires you to **manage** your money.

Answer (score 1):

The etymology shows a concern with settlement of debt or payment contract.

[**finance**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/finance) : "an end [of the debt], settlement [thereof] ..." from *fin* etc.

similar to

[**mortgage**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/mortgage) : *mort gaige*, literally "dead pledge". So called because the deal dies either when the debt is paid or when payment fails.